# BitTorrent encryption in transmission of data

Tags: encryption, p2p, bittorrent

Correct me if i am wrong with my understanding:

`BitTorrent` is a protocol used for `P2P sharing` and it is used by torrent client. BitTorrent protocol have ability to download the files in chunks. Once all the chunks are downloaded the torrent client application will merge them in a single file.

Is there any encryption method is used while transmission of data by BitTorrent protocol or torrent application?
I have seen BitTorrent was earlier open source but after release version 6 it is no more open source. It is about protocol or BitTorrent Client?

Please clear my doubt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern BitTorrent clients support [protocol encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_protocol_encryption). You can find the specification [here](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Message_Stream_Encryption).